# php twig multilanguage without gettext

Tags: php, twig, translation, multilingual

I am novice in php and I write my first web page using PHP + JS without any frameworks (maybe later).

I have the next question.

**How to implement multi language in Twig without Gettext or other plugins?**

Something like that (in pure PHP - no questions... but how use it in twig)

```
$lang=array(
"about_site" => "о нас",
"project" => "проект",
"team" => "команда");
```

In fact my project has no restrictions.
If Gettext is the best solution for me - I'll use it. 
I thought I'll have to translate only 5-10 words per page. Using Gettext for this purpose is a bit strange.

Comment: Why the restriction against gettext?

Comment: When you say without gettext or other plugins do you mean PHP extensions or does that include Twig extensions as well. There is already a translation extension for twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html

Comment: If Gettext is the best solution for me - I'll use it. My project has no restrictions. I thought I'll have to translate only 5-10 words per page. Using Gettext for this purpose is a bit strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a php array like yours for translation in twig. Just pass the array to the twig template:

```
/* $twig is a is an instance of Twig_Environment */
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('yourtemplate.html');

$templateVars['trans'] = array(
  "about_site" => "о нас",
  "project" => "проект",
  "team" => "команда"
);
echo $template->render($templateVars);
```

And in the template:

```
<!-- a lot of html stuff -->
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">{{ trans.about_site }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">{{ trans.project }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">{{ trans.team }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

But mind, if you have complex translations with singular/plural expressions, variables, date expressions etc. I would strongly recommend you to use the twig i18n extension that is built upon gettext:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html